# Limiting the lifetime of data in Django

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I have a model in Django that holds some data which is irrelevant after a month.
Is there a way to automatically delete it after a certain period of time?

The DB is MySQL if it matters, thing is I can't tell whether this is done in the DB side (perhaps there's a way to configure this via MySQL?), or in my back-end code.

Is there a quick solution, or do I have to write code that does this, and have it run every day, deleting anything that wasn't added a month ago?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always let the manager filter for you:

```
class RecentManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(
                RecentManager,
                self
                    ).get_queryset().filter(
            your_timestamp__gt=datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(30)
                                            )

class YourModel(models.Model):
    #your fields, including your_timestamp
    objects = RecentManager()
    unrestricted = models.Manager()

    @static
    def delete_old():
        YourModel.unrestricted.filter(
            your_timestamp__lt=datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(30)
                ).delete()
```

Hook up the delete to a management command which you can run in a cronjob or Celery task or whichever other infrastructure you have handy for async execution.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest creating a management command that queries for all the records in your model that are older than one month and delete those records.  Then throw that management command into a daily cronjob.  This should suit your needs.

Comment: And is that better than simply having a delete_old_data.py file which deletes everything that isn't from the last 30 days? I mean I just want to understand why that's a better logic than having an external file do the job.

Comment: It's pretty much the same thing, except that if you turn delete_old_data.py into a management command, you could run it via manage.py which takes care of setting the Django context for you.

Answer (score 2):

you can solve this issue depends on your case,
if this data become with no value and you want to delete it
you can do that by

**1- from database & using crontab**

DELETE FROM mytable 
WHERE date_field < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY));

**2- using managment command with crontab**

> import datetime
>
> samples = Sample.objects.filter(sampledate__gt=datetime.date(2011, 1,
>   1),                           sampledate__lt=datetime.date(2011, 1, 31))

**3- using celery with periodic task**

http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html